# How to destroy a service instance in angular?

Tags: angular

In my Angular app I need to share a service instance between one component to another component, and after that destroy the service instance, how to do that?

```
       AppModule
     /          \
 Module1        Module2
   /               \
ProductComponent    LogComponent              ? LogService
```

The `ProductComponent`:

```
   constructor(private _logService: LogService) { }

   viewLog() {
      this._logService.productId = this.product.id;
      this._router.navigate(['/app/administration/logs']);
   }
```

The LogComponent :

```
  constructor(private _logService: LogService, private _adminService: AdminService) {

       this._adminService.getLogs(_logService.productId).subscribe(.....);
  }
```

I put the `LogService` on `AppModule` to create a Singleton. It works ok, but i dont want to keep this `LogService` instance after the user leaves the `LogComponent`. I need to destroy it. How can I do that?

Comment: then place it in the providers array of logComponent  and it will be destroyed along with the component and created for every new user

Comment: Well, if i do that ill lost the `this._logService.productId` that i set on the  ProductComponent

Comment: ya this is something you will loose , can i ask why such a requirement ?

Comment: yes you can. All activities in the app are logged, so the user can see it on the LogComponent. But if the user is on the ProductComponent and he wants to see all the logs associated with a speciefic product, the user can navigate to the LogComponent with the speciefic filters set on the ProductComponent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't do what you are asking. My suggestion would be to include a function in `LogService` that will clear out the data you want to get rid of once it's been used. For example:

```
export class CurrentUserService {
  productId: number | null;

  clearProductId() {
    this.productId = null;
  }
}
```

And simply call it when you want to "destroy your service" because you can't actually destroy the service when you're providing it in this way. If you were to somehow actually destroy the service at the `AppModule` level, any component which uses that service would fail, including your `LogComponent`, because it depends on that injection.

Comment: Nice idea. I created a `reset()` that I can call when my component using the service is destroyed

Answer (score -1):

```
@Component({
   selector : 'your-selector',
   template : 'your template',
   providers: [LogService]
})
export class LogComponent {
  // your implementation here
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?